# How to use custom font from String.xml file

Tags: java, android, arrays

Here is the my string array..here is the question how to apply custom font through java code.

Here string array declare to get resource from array-->

```
navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/BRADHITC.TTF");
```

Please share your knowledge..thank for advance.

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
        <item >Home</item>
        <item >Temples</item>
        <item >Resorts</item>
        <item >Travels</item>
        <item >Colleges</item>
        <item >Queries</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: My question is how to apply custom font for string array..

Comment: You can't apply a font to a string... but to its container, such as a TextView. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `font` to `string` or `string-array` . `Font` need to be applied to a `TextView` , so that the text style on the view will change depends on the font.

Create your own custom font

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/BRADHITC.TTF");
```

And, then set it to the `TextView` like this

```
textView.setTypeface(face);
```

If you are setting the `string-array` items to a `listView` , then you need to create a  `Custom Adapter`, and when the item view is created , set the font to the item `TextView`